# How to add captions to slideshow

Tags: jquery, html, css

i tried many ways to add captions to my slideshow, but couldn't. just want add a div on the bottom of each image, should i change my script? or should add something else?

**HTML:**

```
<div class="minislider">
     <img src="http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/wp-content/themes/NMFE/images/fullscreen/1.jpg" />
     <img src="http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/wp-content/themes/NMFE/images/fullscreen/2.jpg" />
     <img src="http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/wp-content/themes/NMFE/images/fullscreen/3.jpg" />
     <img src="http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/wp-content/themes/NMFE/images/fullscreen/4.jpg" />
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.minislider {
    width: 321px;
    height: 242px;
    background-color: #649696;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    left: 76px;
    top: 11px;
    border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
}

.minislider img {
    width: 311px;
    height: 232px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 5px;
    top: 5px;
}
```

**JQUERY:**

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    $('.minislider img:gt(0)').hide();
    setInterval(function(){
        $('.minislider :first-child').fadeOut()
            .next('img').fadeIn()
            .end().appendTo('.minislider');
        }, 3000);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pedram68/tntpQ/

Comment: I think you should change your HTML. Wrap the image and caption in another div or another HTML element.

Comment: it make sense but doesn't work. i put each img with caption into a div, but doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Putvande said, you would have to wrap your image and caption in a div, then you would only have to edit your jQuery a bit:

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    $('.minislider>div:gt(0)').hide(); //".minislider>div" instead of ".minislider div" in case you were planning on putting a div inside your div.
    setInterval(function(){
        $('.minislider>div:first-child').fadeOut()
            .next('div').fadeIn()
            .end().appendTo('.minislider');
        }, 3000);
});
```

Comment: Yeah, Thanks, i tried .minislider div:gt(0) that time, missed the >. thank you for your answer. it works.